# Coverting an int to a different base. php, .NET

Tags: .net, php

Hey I have seen sites that instead of an int show you a string.

For example `d2fr4st == 147392525` and `d2fr4ss == 147392524`. What base is this? And how can I do the same conversion in php and .NET?

At the moment converting from `147392524` to `d2fr4ss` would be most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .Net there's an implementation here: [base36](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/base36.aspx)

```
UInt64ToBase36(147392524); //2FR4SS
UInt64ToBase36(147392525); //2FR4ST
```

Like VolkerK said I'd assume the d is an identifier perhaps just to show that the string is a base36 number if it's using more bases.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo base_convert(147392524 , 10, 36), "\n";
```

prints `2fr4ss`. The leading *d* might be an identifier or some kind of checksum  ...or simply a typo?

see http://docs.php.net/base_convert

Answer (score 0):

It's probably [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). PHP has [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php), ASP.NET has [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx)